# (SOLVED) No Internet on Ubuntu 18.04 after Win 10 BIOS update

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, lenovo

[EDIT: problem solved. Disabling Secure Boot, which got back up, did the trick.]

I had a laptop service point install Ubuntu 18.03 on my IdeaPad L340 with Win 10 preinstalled to achieve dual boot mode. I worked great - for a week. Lenovo updates kicked in, including a BIOS update and the boot menu disappeared.

I entered BIOS to change boot order and moved Ubuntu to the first spot. That did the trick and the boot menu is back. However, for some bizarre reason, Ubuntu is now disconnected from the Internet, prompting: no WiFi adapter available. (It was the same when I first tried installing Ubuntu on this machine by myself, so the update must have reset something). On Windows 10 WiFi works fine, as it used to on the said Ubuntu.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: Here’s the output: https://ibb.co/DMb2xmM (Edit how?)

Comment: Please [don’t add “SOLVED” to the title](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/7413/250300). In order to mark your question _solved_ in the right way, you should [_accept_ the answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) (by clicking the tick mark (✓) next to it) that helped you. If you solved your problem yourself, please [post an answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer) below. In this case, you'll have to wait 2 days before being able to accept it.